# Optimizing evaluation time

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following code and it takes like foreeeeever to evaulate:

```
Table[Table[{If[closeN[[x]] > Max@priceRange[[y]], 1, 
    If[closeN[[x]] < Min@priceRange[[y]], -1, 0]], 
   DateString /@ Extract[date, Position[closeN, closeN[[x]]]]}, {x, 1,
    Length[closeN]}], {y, 1, Length[priceRange]}]
```

What it basically does is looking when a price is greater (assigns a 1), smaller (a -1) or in between (0) a priceRange. It also extracts the date of the prices from closeN.

I always do it in this way, but I realize it might not be an optimal and fast way.

Any ideas or assumptions how to optimize the evaluation time?

here is a small subset:

```
date={{2000, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2000, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, {2000, 2, 4, 0, 0, 
      0.}, {2000, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, {2000, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, {2000, 2, 9, 0,
       0, 0.}, {2000, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, {2000, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, {2000, 2,
       14, 0, 0, 0.}, {2000, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0.}}

   closeN= {0.9766, 0.9899, 0.9838, 0.981, 0.9861, 0.9933, 0.9852, 0.9808,
    0.9791, 0.9816}

priceRange={{0.8273}, {0.8301}, {0.8394, 0.8354, 0.8363, 0.8393, 0.8383, 
  0.8396}, {0.8437, 0.8425, 0.8401, 0.844, 0.84, 0.8449, 0.8444, 
  0.8445}, {0.8494, 0.8491, 0.8485, 0.845, 0.8483, 0.8463, 0.8468, 
  0.8499, 0.8478, 0.8474, 0.8466, 0.8483, 0.8489}, {0.8532, 0.8546, 
  0.8517, 0.8507, 0.8545, 0.8541, 0.851, 0.8527, 0.8549, 0.8517, 
  0.8511, 0.8534, 0.8541, 0.8541, 0.8528}, {0.8587, 0.857, 0.8585, 
  0.8557, 0.8579, 0.8567, 0.8579, 0.8561, 0.8575, 0.8558, 0.8573, 
  0.8561, 0.8555, 0.8554, 0.8557, 0.855, 0.8581, 0.8596, 0.8598, 
  0.8559, 0.8582, 0.855, 0.8596, 0.8593}, {0.8639, 0.8601, 0.8646, 
  0.861, 0.863, 0.8612, 0.8635, 0.8608, 0.8611, 0.8617, 0.8606, 
  0.8631, 0.8608, 0.8608, 0.8636, 0.8618, 0.8622, 0.8621, 
  0.8638}, {0.867, 0.8695, 0.8687, 0.8685, 0.8655, 0.8677, 0.8662, 
  0.8657, 0.8695, 0.8652, 0.865, 0.8698, 0.8672, 0.8668, 0.8694, 
  0.8691, 0.866, 0.8693, 0.8655, 0.8699}, {0.8717, 0.8725, 0.8747, 
  0.8721, 0.8729, 0.8747, 0.8736, 0.8722, 0.8719, 0.8732, 0.8747, 
  0.8703, 0.8729, 0.871, 0.8742, 0.8736, 0.8706, 0.8704, 0.8717, 
  0.8747, 0.8726, 0.8713, 0.8723, 0.8747}}
```

here is whole the data (just copy it into mathematica and evaluate, then it should work):

closeN: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19921198/closeN.txt

date: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19921198/date.txt

priceRange: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19921198/priceRange.txt

Comment: forgot, sorry..see above

Comment: Having a small data subset in the question would be so much more comfortable than having to browse three files. A self-contained question will also be more robust with regard to changing/removed links.

Comment: ok no problem :)..edited it. But with this small subset it evaluates pretty fast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateString` can be a slowpoke without an explicit output element specification. Also, you can apply it to your list of dates before you put them through your evaluation. Finally, you could also replace your `Table` expressions (and that `Position`/`Extract` usage) with `Map` and `MapThread`, along with some other small optimizations:

Here's an example modification run against your full dataset:

```
In[99]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 dateStrs =
  DateString[#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day"}] & /@ date;
 result =
  With[{pMin = Min@#, pMax = Max@#},
     MapThread[
      Function[{c, d},
       {Piecewise@{{-1, c < pMin}, {1, c > pMax}}, d}
       ],
      {closeN, dateStrs}
      ]
     ] & /@ priceRange;
 ]

Out[99]= {1.611161, Null}
```

Compare to the original:

```
In[100]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 result =
   Table[
    Table[
     {If[closeN[[x]] > Max@priceRange[[y]],
       1,
       If[closeN[[x]] < Min@priceRange[[y]],
        -1,
        0
        ]
       ],
      DateString /@
       Extract[date,
        Position[closeN, closeN[[x]]]
        ]},
     {x, 1, Length[closeN]}
     ],
    {y, 1, Length[priceRange]}
    ];
 ]

Out[100]= {513.685032, Null}
```

The pre-application of DateString to your list of date lists with an explicit output element spec seems to be the major performance booster here. Keeping your program style functional and controlling evaluation well always helps, too.

Small notes: (1) The changes I made give you a differently formatted date string, but you can change that to whatever you want with the output element specification; (2) The changes I made give you a date string that is not enclosed in braces by itself. If you want the date enclosed in braces, you can change `d` to `{d}` in the body of the inner Function.

Comment: Thank you!It's quite a different way, trying to understand it now :). With my computer it takes 6 seconds to evaluate ;).